# which algorithm is used to find a leaf in a tree?

Tags: graph-theory

If we have a tree $T$=$G(V,E)$.

What is the best algorithm used to find the leaf?

Is it **DFS**: Depth First Search ?

Comment: Any leaf, or a particular leaf?

Comment: Does it matter? Suppose to find all leavs no particular leaf..

Comment: If you want to find just one leaf you can do depth first search. To find all the leaves it doesn't matter which search method you use, you're going to have to traverse the whole tree. The gain in speed in using depth first search in the first case is only significant if the tree is wide.

Comment: correct answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Question has already been adequately answered in comments; continues to hang around looking unanswered]

There is no generally correct answer as a pathological tree can always be constructed for which the algorithm you choose performs worse than any other distinct algorithm.

OP has accepted the suggestion in comments that Depth First Search is a reasonably option if the branching factor is low (tree not "too wide").